# How to use jQuery to load different images on specific pages in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I'm newish to jQuery and hoping to use it primarily when working on Wordpress websites like this instance.

I am trying to load a unique logo on three specific portfolio pages. My aim is to use a unique class from each page and then add the image before a button with an ID of #scroll-down. Oddly, only the **GPD_Logo_Colour1.gif** shows up on all the pages. When I view the source code for the HTML markup I can see that jQuery loaded 2 of the three image with the GPD_Logo_Colour1.gif first, even though it is second in the jQuery code.

Do I have some incorrect syntax? or is the GPD_Logo_Colour1.gif cached? I'm really not sure where to look next for an answer. Thanks!

**This is the code I've used in my functions.php file, in my child theme, to get the my.js file to be enqueued / load.**

```
function evoc_child_script() {
wp_enqueue_script ('jquery');
wp_enqueue_script('jeremys javascript', 
get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/my.js', 
true);
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'evoc_child_script');
```

**This the code in my my.js file**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

$('body.postid-239 #scroll-down' ).before('<img      src="http://jeremynewcombe.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/FI30_Logo.gif"      />');

$('body.postid-192 #scroll-down' ).before('<img    src="http://jeremynewcombe.com/wp-  content/uploads/2015/09/GPD_Logo_Colour1.gif" />');

$('body.postid-284 #scroll-down' ).before('<img src="http://jeremynewcombe.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/Dynamis_Logo_White.gif" />');

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you perhaps missing a space before `#scroll-down`?
What's you're targetting now is a body tag with the class `post-idXXX` that also has the ID `scroll-down`.

Comment: You're right there was a space missing between .postid-XXX and #scroll-down. Refreshed the site and still getting the same error. Only one image is showing up on all the pages...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can't use the dollar sign shortcut in your code like that unless you pass it to the function:

jQuery( function($) {

//Now you can use it

$('.selector')....

});

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! A couple of things to help you get into the swing of things. When you're including code, be sure to use the appropriate formatting for it. You can see the formatting help here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting In addition, to directly address your answer, jQuery assigns $ as a `window` variable, allowing it to be used across the window scope, just as jQuery can be used in the same context. Be sure to read the rules and guidelines if you haven't already for the site, and once again, welcome! http://stackoverflow.com/help

Comment: Thanks, will do. For the record though, I believe Wordpress unassigns the dollar sign for compatibility with other plugins that may use other javascript libraries.

Comment: It's possible, though from a quick perusal through the WordPress repository, it doesn't appear that WordPress, or any of its default themes dealiases `$`, which is typically done by calling jQuery.noConflict(). In which case, yes, `$` would have to be passed back in. Typically this is done with a self-executing closure, passing in jQuery to a self executing function which has `$` as an argument. It's possible that another theme is doing this, but it doesn't by default, at least from what I can tell.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the $. I've added that in but still getting the same bug... I'll continue to research.

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_Wrappers